# Repairing a big gap in stone foundation wall under a window

Tags: concrete, walls

I am going to repair a relatively big hole beneath a rotten window frame (about 12cm deep). I am looking for tips on how to do this. I was thinking about filling it up with small rocks and pouring over concrete.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that a _door_? Why is the hole present in the first place? Is the foundation collapsing?

Comment: Indeed, this issue would seem to need some deeper digging, so to speak.